# function of series after integral

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

$Σ((x+1)^(2n))/(2^n * (n+1))$     from $n = 0$ to infinity . I would like to see how you are handling it , the only thing i do right is calculating the area of convergence $<-1 - \sqrt{2} , -1 + \sqrt{2}$ . However i cannot go further ... Can someone help me to provide this series to a function which we receive after doing an integral ... I tried to do $(x+1)^2 = (t+1)$ but i  still  miss something i guess ... i think i should receive sth with natural logarithm ...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand there is $S(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n \ge 0} \dfrac{(x+1)^{2n}}{2^n(n+1)}$.

Consider $F(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n \ge 0} \dfrac{(x+1)^{2n+1}}{2^n} = -\dfrac{2(x+1)}{x^2 + 2x - 1} $. Now we have $\displaystyle \int F(x)dx = \sum_{n\ge0} \dfrac{(x+1)^{2n} \cdot(x+1)^2}{2\cdot2^n (n+1)} + C = S(x) \cdot \dfrac{(x+1)^2}{2}$

Now it's easy to find your $S(x)$